# Freebsd 9 on Z68 chipset support

Tags: freebsd

Does Freebsd 9  support Z68 chipset like in Intel DZ68BC motherboard? Will I have any "unrecognized device" issues ?
What about Freebsd 8?
What's the best way to find it out ?

Comment: testing it would be the best way IMO :p

Comment: I need to purchase the hardware, so if it is not supported, I'll be in trouble. First of all I don't really understand if the north bridge Intel Z68 requires any drivers from the OS. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question, but I want to be sure before I buy anything. I check http://www.freebsd.org/relnotes/CURRENT/hardware/index.html and it doesn't mention anything about mother board chipsets.

Comment: http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=23813

Comment: It looks like nobody mentioned anything there about unrecognized devices on P8Z68-V PRO (Z68 chipset) in freebsd 8.2. So I guess I'll be fine installing the OS on it. Thanks Lucas, it really helped!

Comment: If you need to buy hardware that you ***KNOW*** works with a specific version of FreeBSD check out [iXsystems](http://www.ixsystems.com/) -  They specifically certify and sell equipment that is compatible with the BSDs.  Otherwise if you're willing to do the research and assume some level of risk check the release notes for the version of FreeBSD you want to use (@Springstern linked to the -CURRENT ones)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing, that is not working with a motherboard as the one you list. 
Even Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics are more or less working by now, which has been an issue for a while.

Since motherboards generally just provide generic I/O stuff there are usually no specific drivers required for their basic functionality is supported by generic drivers.

Additional SATA Controllers sometimes tend to be rather esoteric and may require additional drivers. For (normal onboard) Sound devices and Networking on the other hand the available chipset choices on the market have become so small by now that you'd probably have trouble finding an unsupported device.